# Cannot get Editor Templates working in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am converting a MVC2 app to MVC3.
I cannot seem to join up a View with an Editor Template.
So in my View the code is;

```
@model IEnumerable<ITOF.Models.LatestContractNumber>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditContractNumbers";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

using (Html.BeginForm())
       {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit Latest Contract Numbers</legend>
        <div style="width:90%">
            <div style="width:45%; float:left; vertical-align:top;">
                <p>A contract number is in a format: AA/B999</p>
                <p>Where AA is a 2 character code for the division, for example CD.</p>
                <p>Where B is a letter for the contract, usually the first letter of the contract title.</p>
                <p>999 is a 3 digit number.</p>
                <p>The 999 number depends on the B letter. </p>
                <p>Initially all the numbers start as 1 and are incremented each time the B letter is used.</p>
                <p>This pages sets the initial 999 number for each B letter.</p>
                <p>Once the application is up and running, this page should be used initially and then no more.</p>  
                @if (TempData["Message"] != null && TempData["Message"].ToString().Trim().Length > 0)
                  { 
                  <p class="success">@TempData["Message"].ToString()</p>
                  }         
            </div>
            <div style="width:45%; float:right; vertical-align:top;">
                <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Letter</td>
                        <td>Number</td>
                    </tr>
                    @Html.EditorForModel(Model)
                </table>
                </div>
                <div style="padding-top:20px">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit Changes" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    }
```

And my Editor Template is in the correct folder and now looks like;

```
@model ITOF.Models.LatestContractNumber
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LatestContractNumberId)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Letter) 
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Number, new { style = "width:30px" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

The Model in @Html.EditorForModel(Model) relates to @model IEnumerable at the top of the page.
In the Editor Template, this should translate to a loop of ITOF.Models.LatestContractNumber, hence at the top of the template I have put @model ITOF.Models.LatestContractNumber

Comment: When you say your Editor Template is in the correct folder, which folder is it in exactly?

Comment: Editor Templates folder which in turn is located in the same folder as the view.

Comment: and what is the name of the EditorTemplate file?

Comment: Good question! I got into the habit of starting each partial view with an _ at the front of the name, but of course that doesn't work for Editor Templates where the name has to match the model name. So I have changed _LatestContractNumber.cshtml to LatestContractNumber.cshtml and now it works! Please put that as the answer if you want me to award you the correct answer.

Comment: Your `@Html.EditorForModel(Model)` call is passing the model as additional view data - you don't need to pass the model to it. It's a good idea to have a template start with `_` as any view starting with this can never be requested directly by an end user. Also, you can pass the template name to `@Html.EditorForModel()` as the first argument, so it becomes `@Html.EditorForModel("_LatestContractNumber")`

Comment: Yes, I corrected that as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question turned out to be a red herring. The real problem was that having migrated to MVC and started prefixing partial views with _, the name of the Editor Template was invalid.
Thanks to Russ Cam for asking the right questions that got me the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are calling `EditorForModel` with a model of type `IEnumerable<ITOF.Models.LatestContractNumber>` (which is the Model for your View) but you should be calling it with `ITOF.Models.LatestContractNumber` (which is the Model your template expects to see/get). You need a `foreach` somewhere in there

```
foreach(ITOF.Models.LatestContractNumber number in Model) {
    @Html.EditorForModel(number)
}
```

Second, not 100% sure, but EditorTemplates should be in Shared folder under the Views folder. So `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/` and should be named after the class name so `LatestContractNumber.cshtml`.

HTH

Comment: I think this is all wrong, sorry! One of the points of using Editor Templates is that you do not have to use a for loop. The Editor Templates folder can either be in the same folder as your View OR in the Shared folder. You use the Shared folder if the template is going to be used by views in different folders, or you think it might be in the future.